# Getting incorrect username and password exception by using `gmailSaslXoauth2`

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, mailer

I am using `mailer` package from dart pub. I created a service account and copied the content of `json` file into class variable `CLIENT_JSON`. You can see some fields of `CLIENT_JSON` in `getAccessToken()` function.

Whenever I try to email someone, an exception is thrown

```dart
SmtpClientAuthenticationException (Incorrect username / password / credentials)
```

Here are two functions I am calling from UI.

```dart
Future<AccessCredentials> getAccessToken() async {
    var accountCredentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson({
      "private_key_id": CLIENT_JSON["private_key_id"],
      "private_key": CLIENT_JSON["private_key"],
      "client_email": CLIENT_JSON["client_email"],
      "client_id": CLIENT_JSON['client_id'],
      "type": "service_account"
    });

    AccessCredentials accessCredentials;
    final client = http.Client();

    try {
      accessCredentials = await obtainAccessCredentialsViaServiceAccount(
          accountCredentials, ["https://mail.google.com/"], client);
      print("[EMAIL_SERVICE] Access Token Fetched");
    } on Exception catch (err) {
      print("[EMAIL_SERVICE] Error in fetching access token. Error: $err");
    }

    client.close();
    return accessCredentials;
  }

  Future<void> sendEmailFromConfibuddy({
    @required String receiverEmail,
    @required String subject,
    @required String body,
  }) async {
    final credentials = await getAccessToken();

    if (credentials == null) {
      print("[EMAIL_SERVICE] Credentials are null.");
      return;
    }

    final smtpServer = gmailSaslXoauth2(
        CLIENT_JSON["client_email"], credentials.accessToken.data);

    final message = Message()
      ..from = Address(CLIENT_JSON["client_email"], 'Confibuddy')
      ..recipients.add("example@gmail.com")
      ..subject = subject
      ..html = body;

    try {
      final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
      print('Message sent: ' + sendReport.toString());
    } on MailerException catch (e) {
      print('Message not sent.');
      for (var p in e.problems) {
        print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Right now, I can generate an access token using the `googleapis_auth` package. But I am confused about which email to put in the `gmailSaslXoauth2` function as the `userEmail` parameter. I have two emails, one is my personal account in which I created the project and created a service account and an email generated in `json` file named as `client_email`.

`client_email` looks like this `example@example.iam.gserviceaccount.com`.